# CLRS Quicksort - Not working correctly

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to implement the Quicksort algorithm as given in the classic CLRS book. I have implemented it *exactly* line-by-line in my C# program. But the output is unsorted. The following is my code in it's entirety, along with the output:

```
using System;

namespace clrs
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = { 2, 1, 4 };
            Console.WriteLine("unsorted: " + string.Join(",", numbers));
            quicksort (numbers, 0, numbers.Length-1);
            Console.WriteLine("sorted: " + string.Join(",", numbers));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            numbers = new int[]{ 7, 2, 1, 6, 1 };
            Console.WriteLine("unsorted: " + string.Join(",", numbers));
            quicksort (numbers, 0, numbers.Length-1);
            Console.WriteLine("sorted: " + string.Join(",", numbers));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            numbers = new int[]{ 2,8,7,1,3,5,6,4 };
            Console.WriteLine("unsorted: " + string.Join(",", numbers));
            quicksort (numbers, 0, numbers.Length-1);
            Console.WriteLine("sorted: " + string.Join(",", numbers));
            Console.WriteLine("");

            numbers = new int[]{ 2, 33, 6, 9, 8, 7, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7 };    
            Console.WriteLine("unsorted: " + string.Join(",", numbers));
            quicksort (numbers, 0, numbers.Length-1);
            Console.WriteLine("sorted: " + string.Join(",", numbers));
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        public static void quicksort(int[] a, int p, int r){
            int q;

            if (p < r){
                q = partition (a, p, r);
                quicksort(a, p, q-1);
                quicksort(a, q+1, r);
            }
        }

        public static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r){
            int x = a[r];
            int i = p - 1;

            for (int j=p; j<r-1; j++){
                if(a[j] <= x){
                    i = i + 1;

                    int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            int temp1 = a[i+1];
            a[i+1] = a[r];
            a[r] = temp1;

            return (i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
unsorted: 2,1,4
sorted: 2,4,1

unsorted: 7,2,1,6,1
sorted: 1,1,2,7,6

unsorted: 2,8,7,1,3,5,6,4
sorted: 2,3,1,4,5,7,8,6

unsorted: 2,33,6,9,8,7,1,2,5,4,7
sorted: 1,2,5,6,7,2,7,8,9,33,4
```

I have implemented quicksort *exactly* as it is given in CLRS, 3rd edition. My code compiles but the output is not completely sorted.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a bug in the CLRS psuedocode (highly unlikely)?

Please HELP!

Comment: Ogling the outputs, can you spot something common to the outputs? Which are the indexes used in the compares in your stab at Lomuto partition?

Comment: @greybeard - Thanks for the quick reply. I have been trying to debug this but as it is an *exact* pseudocode implementation, shouldn't it work 'out-of-the-box'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call shenanigans... It seems someone made a typo

This

```
for (int j=p; j<r-1; j++){
```

should be this

```
for (int j=p; j<r; j++){
```

**Test here**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XgIOpx

**For reference**

[Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Here is the *Lomuto partition* algorithm from wiki

```
algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi) is
    if lo < hi then
        p := partition(A, lo, hi)
        quicksort(A, lo, p - 1 )
        quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)

algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[hi]
    i := lo - 1    
    for j := lo to hi - 1 do
        if A[j] < pivot then
            i := i + 1
            swap A[i] with A[j]
    swap A[i + 1] with A[hi]
    return i + 1
```

However you need to take special note of

```
for j := lo to hi - 1 do   // note the - 1
    if A[j] < pivot then   // and <
```

it needs to be either **- 1**  or **<=** , not both

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!! I had been banging my head on the wall for the past two days but unable to get it to work. Once I make this modification then the arrays are properly sorted. Does this mean that there is a bug in CLRS Quicksort pseudocode?

Comment: @SuyashGupta updated to show you why it was wrong, its a very simple mistake

Comment: I looked at Errata for CLRS 3rd Ed - https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrs-bugs/bugs-3e.php. But this 'bug' wasn't listed there. So is it a confirmed bug/typo?

Comment: @SuyashGupta im not sure... someone is wrong though